# try_files directive multiple options not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have the following code:

```
server {
       .....
       root /user/share/nginx/html;

      rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 redirect; 

      location / { 
       try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri index.html =404;
    }
```

1. In the rewrite I remove the `.html` extension from file
2. In location I `uri` corresponding file is not found I offer a set of other options.
   The last one before the error code is index.html; index.html exist but always I get the 404;

Answer (score 0):

All Nginx URIs begin with a leading `/`. Use: `/index.html`.

For example:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri /index.html;
}
```